# Fetch the list on my table in reverse way

Tags: php, html, mysql

How can I fetch the list on my table in reverse order?

Like for example:

The records are

> 1 2 3 4 5

I want it in reverse

> 5 4 3 2 1

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
$run = $con->query($query);
while($row = $run->fetch_array()):
    ?>
        <div id="chat_data">
            <table id="chattbl">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3><?php echo $row['name']; ?>:</h3>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p><?php echo $row['msg']; ?></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <h5><?php echo formatDate($row['date']); ?></h5>
        </div>
```

Comment: if you want the array the other way around, why not just reverse your sort in your query? `ASC LIMIT 10`?

Comment: Even beginners need to google.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `ASC` instead of `DESC` for switching the order of your records:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: thank you sir, and sorry for my wrong grammar,,.